# Is there a way to log DB connection details (username, connection string) for every DB request in Spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have setup multiple data sources and I want to show in the logs the specific connection being used for some requests for debugging purposes, is there a way to log DB connection details (username or connection string) for every request made to the DB?

Comment: you would need a proxy around the datasource to do that. Checkout https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli that article doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a datasource proxy for logging.

First you have to add a new dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gavlyukovskiy</groupId>
    <artifactId>datasource-proxy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to configure logging in the `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener=debug
```

Now you'll see the datasource name in the logs

```
2022-12-07 08:14:56.294 DEBUG 36832 --- [main] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : 
Name:dataSource, Connection:5, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)"]
Params:[(Peter Muster,1)]
```

To fully answer your question: It's not possible to log username, password, and URL. This wouldn't be secure anyway. The datasource name should be good enough.

Source: https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/

Comment: The `name` shows up the same for both data sources. How can I affect the value that shows up there? I tried using the datasource `name` property and it's not having an effect.

Comment: How did you configure the datasources?

Comment: I'm configuring multiple datasources, using more or less this approach: https://dzone.com/articles/read-replicas-and-spring-data-part-4-configuring-t

Answer (score 1):

With Spring boot, adding below in properties/yaml should log the details :
`logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG`